# Do sed-like delete commands in vim

Tags: vim

I'm comfortable doing search/replace in vim, but how do I delete all lines in a file (or between certain lines) if they match a condition? Currently I shell out and run a sed command, for example:

```
sed -i '/^CRITICAL/d' hosts
```

(delete all the lines that start with CRITICAL from the hosts file).

How would I do this in vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess the best way would be to use the `ex` command `g`.

```
:g/^CRITICAL/d
```

would do the same as your sed command.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about :g. Nice explanation here: http://www.sbf5.com/~cduan/technical/vi/vi-2.shtml